# How To Configure liferay tomcat server to read the file from another liferay tomcat server?

Tags: java, tomcat, liferay

I want to access a file which is on remote liferay server.
I succeed Through apache httpclient from java main method program and it will read file and convert as i want but when i moved that code to liferay server as per my requirement it was not able to read the file and convert it into tiff image file 
i have used all the jars file which is required to conversion and also included the same jars when i tried from java main method program.

My question is that will i need any external server configuration to achive my requirement?

Below is the code what i have used in my main program

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080"
                + StringPool.SLASH + "AtalasoftScan" + StringPool.SLASH
                + "atala-capture-upload" + StringPool.SLASH + headerFileName);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        File tempFile = new File(System.getProperty("catalina.base")
                + File.separator + "webapps" + File.separator + "AtalasoftScan"
                + File.separator + "atala-capture-upload" + File.separator
                + headerFileName);
        InputStream fileStream=response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(fileStream);
        ImageIO.write(image, "bmp", tempFile);
```

Same code i have written in my method which is on the liferay server.

From liferay server i am to open the connection and but when

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(fileStream);
```

Image is not getting from the inputStream.

Any Suggestion for that would be helpfull.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you make sure you can basically get the resource from your tomcat server. Try using: `wget -v http://host/path/to/image`. You said that the image is on a different tomcat server, but you are using localhost:8080 (or do you have multiple tomcat with different port on your machine?)

Comment: Yes i have different server with different port number

Comment: did you test the HttpGet URL in your code block with wget? Do you get an exception in your ImageIO.read call

Answer (score 3):

Note that it's extremely bad practice to copy random stuff into tomcat's webapps directory that's unrelated to deploying a new web application: You're risking to loose your uploaded content any time your application is being updated, or you risk any disaster recovery being impossible because you're missing files there.

At best, your solution is a quick hack, but no solution that you should keep up for a long time. And this way to solve problems (if used multiple times) will only create an unmaintainable conglomerate of applications that you'll never be able to quickly upgrade to the next version of any of the involved applications (even in the case of security fixes being released).

That being said, it's good to see that you figured out you don't need the "image" intermediary step - it's enough to just copy the data if you indeed just want to copy a resource to another place - well - that is unless you want to make sure that you're actually copying an image. Especially with setups where people copy files into webapps at runtime, there's an attack vector: Just imagine someone uploading an arbitrary JSP file and you're victim of server-side-code-execution.

Comment: That code Is just For Copying the temporary image then after upload to cloud it deleting from that folder as well as from Localserver also.

Comment: If You Think This Is still a problem then can you suggest me any other way from which i can achieve my requirement that is scanning from other server then copy that data into local server then upload to Cloud.

Comment: well, while the file is there, you're still subject to all possible attacks - short time is enough. Just use any other temporary directory for saving the file before uploading it. No need for a webapps subdirectory.

Answer (score -1):

I found the Work Solution for that Just Used apache Commons io.
It will directly copy the inputStream which is coming from remote server to local File System

Below is the Code Snippet

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080"
                + StringPool.SLASH + "AtalasoftScan" + StringPool.SLASH
                + "atala-capture-upload" + StringPool.SLASH + headerFileName);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        HttpEntity httpEntity=response.getEntity();
        InputStream inputStream=httpEntity.getContent();
        System.out.println(inputStream);
        File tempFile = new File(System.getProperty("catalina.base")
                + File.separator + "webapps" + File.separator + "AtalasoftScan"
                + File.separator + "atala-capture-upload" + File.separator
                + headerFileName);
    FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream, tempFile);
```